# How to connect from Linux to a Windows printer?

Tags: windows, linux, samba, network-printer, pclinuxos

My home network has a Windows computer with a shared printer. I've just installed Linux on my own machine. **How can I connect to the shared Windows printer from my Linux installation?**

Details:

1. Assume my SSID is `wlan` and the Windows machine is called `win-pc` and is sharing the printer as `printer`.
2. From my Windows installation, I can reach the shared printer using `\\win-pc\printer`, and that works.
3. From my Linux installation (PCLinuxOS), I can reach the other computer using `smb:/win-pc` and I can see some shared folders (such as `smb:/win-pc/documents`) but I cannot see the printer. Based on this, I think Samba is installed and working correctly.
4. I've looked at several [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=connect+linux+to+windows+printer) but they are not specific enough.
5. The **KDE Print** *Add Printer Wizard* provides three textfields to enter SSID, Server, and Printer. I assume that no `/` are required. Still, entering `wlan` and `win-pc` and `printer` does not work.
6. I will not change anything on the Windows pc. The solution must be on my Linux pc.

I must have missed some piece of configuration or something, but I don't know what my next step should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go through the control panel, there's an "automatic" option that worked.

PCLinux Control Center:
-> Hardware
-> Set up printers
-> Add printer
-> Auto-detect printers connected to machines running Windows

Comment: I was going to suggest asking CUPS directly at http://localhost:631/

Comment: I tried CUPS as you suggest too, and that also failed. I don't know what's so magic about this _auto-detect_ but it did _something_ that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I have pretty much just done what you have without any problems.

You have missed a few things such as what the problem actually is / where the error occurs (or I have misread).

Go to the website of your printer manufacturer and see if you find any updated Linux drivers that may help you.

I used the wizard last time I needed to do this then updated with the drivers I downloaded, I had no problems, but again, I can't really help without knowing the exact problem you are having.

Comment: The printer driver (on the Windows machine) is up to date. I want to connect to the printer from a Linux machine. I don't get an error message -- I don't get any result at all. I had expected to find the printer listed along with the shared folders on the Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add a printer using that wizard by selecting the "SMB shared printer (Windows)" option, and using smb:/win-pc/printer as the location for the printer.  It should then ask for the type of printer so that it can setup the right drivers.

Comment: Yep, that's what I expected. Except that it didn't find any printer, so I could not continue.