# How to cat a local file to a remote printer using Linux

Tags: terminal, cat

On DOS we can:

```
NET USE LPT1: \\remote-pc\shared_printer
COPY file.txt > LPT1
```

I know on Linux I can print to local usb printer:

```
cat file.txt > /dev/usb/lp2
```

But how to print to a remote (Linux Shared Printer) AND to a (Windows Shared Printer) ?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux client, you could use `lp` when executed by `ssh` on the
remote machine, as it can
read from `stdin` data that is coming from outside the `ssh` call.

This might work:

```
cat file | ssh user@remotehost "lp -"
```

A more sophisticated script can be found on the Web Archive at
[SSH-LPR Backend for CUPS](https://web.archive.org/web/20110521094733/http://www.masella.name/technical/sshlpr.html).

---

For accessing a Windows shared printer from Linux, see the post
[How to connect from Linux to a Windows printer?](https://superuser.com/questions/70557/how-to-connect-from-linux-to-a-windows-printer)